# T-sql table group by type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

i have a table called HybridCount with data like this

[image]

But i am trying to write a query that will group the data in the above table to look like below

[image]

I have wrote the below query, but its choping off the 6th row

```
select distinct firstcount.itemcode, firstcount.bincode, firstcount.docentry,  firstcount.countqty  countqty_forFirstCount,  secondcount.countqty countqty_forSecondCount 
from  [dbo].[HybridCount] firstcount cross join hybridcount secondcount 
Where firstcount.itemcode= secondcount.itemcode and secondcount.CountType = 'second count'
and firstcount.CountType = 'First count'
```

NB
itemcode is sku, 
 There are 2 count types 'First count' and 'second count'.
The first time a user counts a location, it is logged as first count
then they can count the location the second time, then it ls logged as second count. Now during second count in the case of the data in that table, the user counted more itemcodes than he did in the firstcount that's why in the 2nd screen shot ( which represents what i want to achieve) the Countqty_firstcount is Null for the itemcode 10006.
It is possible that the user could have counted more distinct itemcodes in first count than secound count , in that case i need the query to show nulls in the first count for that itemcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume the CountType will not duplicate for each group.

Use group by and `SUM()`. If the SUM() is all NULLs, it will select NULL.

```
SELECT 
    itemcode, bincode, docentry, 
    SUM(CASE CountType WHEN 'First count' THEN countqty END) AS countqty_forFirstCount,
    SUM(CASE CountType WHEN 'second count' THEN countqty END) AS countqty_forSecondCount
FROM 
    [dbo].[HybridCount]
GROUP BY
    itemcode, bincode, docentry
```

Comment: Actually @Used_By_Already post his answer first, also vote up to him

Answer (score 2):

No need for "select distinct" or "cross join". All you need here is GROUP BY and some "conditional aggregates" - here we use MAX(case ... end)

```
SELECT
      itemcode
    , bincode
    , docentry
    , MAX(case when CountType = 'First count'  then countqty end) countqty_forFirstCount
    , MAX(case when CountType = 'second count' then countqty end) countqty_forSecondCount
FROM [dbo].[HybridCount]
GROUP BY
      itemcode
    , bincode
    , docentry
```